# Error while executing Hive query from Beeswax web ui (HUE)

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, beeswax

I am trying to run a hive query from Hue - Beeswax.
when i am running the same query from shell i an able to sucessfully execute the query.
But from Beeswax i am getting the following error.

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
14/12/09 01:45:17 ERROR ql.Driver: FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
14/12/09 01:45:17 INFO ql.Driver: </PERFLOG method=Driver.execute start=1418118313716 end=1418118317152 duration=3436>
14/12/09 01:45:17 ERROR beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl: Exception while processing query
BeeswaxException(message:Driver returned: -101.  Errors: OK
converting to local servername/user/hadoop/TimeFilter.jar
Added /tmp/5f47789f-28e4-4b94-a7de-80371b6e99c8_resources/TimeFilter.jar to class path
Added resource: /tmp/5f47789f-28e4-4b94-a7de-80371b6e99c8_resources/TimeFilter.jar
OK
Hive history file=/tmp/hue/hive_job_log_5f47789f-28e4-4b94-a7de-80371b6e99c8_1038714496.txt
Total MapReduce jobs = 2
Launching Job 1 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
, log_context:9f375bf4-a632-4448-acd0-8a20b2eaf098, handle:QueryHandle(id:9f375bf4-a632-4448-acd0-8a20b2eaf098, log_context:9f375bf4-a632-4448-acd0-8a20b2eaf098), SQLState:     )
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState.execute(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:351)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState$1$1.run(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:609)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState$1$1.run(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:598)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1418)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState$1.run(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:598)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
14/12/09 01:45:18 WARN conf.HiveConf: DEPRECATED: Configuration property hive.metastore.local no longer has any effect. Make sure to provide a valid value for hive.metastore.uris if you are connecting to a remote metastore.
14/12/09 01:45:18 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:admin (auth:SIMPLE) cause:BeeswaxException(message:Driver returned: -101.  Errors: OK
converting to local serverName/user/hadoop/TimeFilter.jar
Added /tmp/5f47789f-28e4-4b94-a7de-80371b6e99c8_resources/TimeFilter.jar to class path
Added resource: /tmp/5f47789f-28e4-4b94-a7de-80371b6e99c8_resources/TimeFilter.jar
OK
Hive history file=/tmp/hue/hive_job_log_5f47789f-28e4-4b94-a7de-80371b6e99c8_1038714496.txt
Total MapReduce jobs = 2
Launching Job 1 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
, log_context:9f375bf4-a632-4448-acd0-8a20b2eaf098, handle:QueryHandle(id:9f375bf4-a632-4448-acd0-8a20b2eaf098, log_context:9f375bf4-a632-4448-acd0-8a20b2eaf098), SQLState:     )
14/12/09 01:45:18 ERROR beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl: Caught BeeswaxException
BeeswaxException(message:Driver returned: -101.  Errors: OK
converting to local serverName/user/hadoop/TimeFilter.jar
Added /tmp/5f47789f-28e4-4b94-a7de-80371b6e99c8_resources/TimeFilter.jar to class path
Added resource: /tmp/5f47789f-28e4-4b94-a7de-80371b6e99c8_resources/TimeFilter.jar
OK
Hive history file=/tmp/hue/hive_job_log_5f47789f-28e4-4b94-a7de-80371b6e99c8_1038714496.txt
Total MapReduce jobs = 2
Launching Job 1 out of 2
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapred.reduce.tasks=<number>
FAILED: Execution Error, return code -101 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
, log_context:9f375bf4-a632-4448-acd0-8a20b2eaf098, handle:QueryHandle(id:9f375bf4-a632-4448-acd0-8a20b2eaf098, log_context:9f375bf4-a632-4448-acd0-8a20b2eaf098), SQLState:     )
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState.execute(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:351)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState$1$1.run(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:609)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState$1$1.run(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:598)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1418)
    at com.cloudera.beeswax.BeeswaxServiceImpl$RunningQueryState$1.run(BeeswaxServiceImpl.java:598)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Do you have any MapReduce logs from Job Browser?

Comment: Hi Romain,
I am unable to paste the entire logs here.
This is teh part of logs from where error has started.

Comment: Which Hue version are you using? If 2.5+ you could use HiveServer2 instead of Beeswax: http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-hive-query-editor-with-hiveserver2-and/